# SP2013 Drag and Drop not working on 1 server out of 3

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a weird issue. We are running SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on a farm of three WFEs and two App boxes. The three WFE boxes are in a load-balancing pool so that one server doesn't get all the traffic. When users connect to one of the WFE servers (let's call it Box 3), they are unable to drag and drop documents into a new library. The error they get is:

> The documents cannot be uploaded because different permissions are
>   needed. Request the necessary permissions.

If they connect to either of the other two WFE servers (Box 1 or 2), everything works normally. The issue can be duplicated, and I've tested with multiple users. The common denominator is definitely which WFE they're getting site content from at the time of the error.

The site is using a custom master page but there aren't any custom ASPX pages or scripts copied into the hive folders on each server. All three servers are running the same build number and services. All three servers *should* be configured exactly the same as well, but obviously something is missing or incorrect on this one server. The correlation IDs & event logs haven't yielded anything helpful as far as I know.

**What configuration setting or file could be causing this issue?**

Comment: have you installed office or designer on any of the sharepoint wfe?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: No, I have both installed on my dev server - which is a totally separate environment - but neither is installed on the production boxes.

Comment: do you know the bad WFE server? clear the config cache on that server.

Comment: How are users connecting to different WFEs? Are they using different URLs?

Comment: @shufler - updated the question. The three WFEs are in a pool using a single URL.

Comment: How are you validating you are hitting BOX3 when it's not working? Are you using the same URL for testing each server?

Comment: @shufler - same url, yes. I have a page that returns all of the IIS header info.

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm my understanding. When you are testing this you send a request to 'http:// sharepointurl'. How are you making sure which server you hit at that point? Is the LB directing to a specific WFE? Are you using a hosts file?

Comment: @shufler - I use a hosts file when reproducing the issue. In the wild, though, I was having users click a link on the site that shows which server they were connected to during that session (via IIS host info). Regardless, I know now that the problem is with "Box 3", I just have no idea what server-specific issues could cause what we're seeing.